# How to delete text in text file in Windows using Perl?

Tags: windows, perl, delete-file

I want to port my perl application to windows.
Currently it calls out to "grep" to delete text in a text file, like so:

```
system("grep -v '$mcadd' $ARGV[0] >> $ARGV[0].bak");
system("mv $ARGV[0].bak $ARGV[0]");
```

This works perfectly well in ubuntu, but I'm not sure (a) how to modify my perl script to achieve the same effect on Windows, and (b) whether there is a way to achieve the effect in a way that will work in both environments.

Comment: `grep` and `File::Copy::move` are available in Perl.

Comment: How to use in windows?

Comment: [`perldoc File::Copy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Copy) and [`perldoc -f grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html)

Comment: `find /v "word" file >file.bak`, though that's super easy to do in Perl.

Comment: There's no point in using perl if you just wrap shell commands in system() calls.  The whole point of perl is to enable you to rise out of the dust and stop scratching around like a chicken.

Comment: Not exactly a perl answer, but if you would like to make the 'grep' and 'mv' unix commands run in windows, you could install the very small MingW - http://www.mingw.org/ suite. Writing portable perl as recommended in the other comments is better if you do not want to introduce that dependency on MinGW. (cygwin is a popular heavyweight alternative to MinGW)

Answer (score 0):

> Other way to delete text in perl?

You can use perl's inplace editing facility.

```
~/pperl_programs$ cat data.txt
hello world
goodbye mars
goodbye perl6
back to perl5
```

Run this:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use 5.020;

my $fname = 'data.txt';

#Always use three arg form of open().
#Don't use bareword filehandles.
#open my $INFILE, '<', $fname  
#    or die "Couldn't open $fname: $!";

{
    local $^I = ".bak";  #Turn on inplace editing for this block only

    local @ARGV = $fname;  #Set @ARGV for this block only

    while (my $line = <>) {  #"diamond operator" reads from @ARGV

        if ($line !~ /hello/) {
            print $line;  #This does not go to STDOUT--it goes to a new file that perl creates for you.
        }
    }

}  #Return $^I and @ARGV to their previous values

#close $INFILE;
```

Here is the result:

```
$ cat data.txt
goodbye mars
goodbye perl6
back to perl5
```

With inplace editing turned on, perl takes care of creating a new file, sending print() output to the new file, then when you are done, renaming the new file to the original file name, and saving a copy of the original file with a .bak extension.

Comment: The open is unnecessary since you use <>.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, Yep.  I changed the code to read from `@ARGV` instead of $INFILE to more closely match the OP's code, and I didn't remember to delete that.

Answer (score -1):

system("perl -n -e 'if(\$_ !~ /$mcadd/) { print \$_; }' \$ARGV[0] >> \$ARGV[0].bak");

system("rename \$ARGV[0].bak \$ARGV[0]");

This should work in windows.

Comment: system("rename \$ARGV[0].bak \$ARGV[0]"); # (backslash is needed before $.)